# How to print argument from created function?

Tags: python

I created a function returning the highest value by using `max()`. As arguments, I inserted a few operations eg. `2+2, 3+5, 5-1`. The `max()` shows the highest value reflecting as a score. How to retrieve an operation and score?

```
def largest_num(*args):
    print(max(args))

largest_num(2+1,30-24,8*3)
```

I would like to retrieve a message: `"max value is 8*3 = 24"`

Comment: That's impossible, because your function did not in any sense receive "8*3" - it merely received the value 24.  You'd have to pass strings, and `eval()` them inside the function.

Comment: @jasonharper `eval` is evil. You don't need it here.

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing `8*3` to your method. You're passing `24`. So if you want to have the original information, you can pass it as a string `"8*3"`, [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) it in the method to get `24` and display the original string.

```
import ast

def largest_num(*args):
    max_item = max(args, key=ast.literal_eval)
    print(f"max value is {max_item} = {ast.literal_eval(max_item)}")

largest_num("2+1", "30-24", "8*3")
```

prints

```
max value is 8*3 = 24
```